# compatible jdk version for controlsfx-8.40.14

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, netbeans-8

i using last version of scene builder with **java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17**
and **NetBeans 8.2**, and trying to import controlsfx-8.40.14.jar;

with analysis report in scene builder i have this errors:

```
Exception for: impl/org/controlsfx/skin/GridRow.class

Exception for: impl/org/controlsfx/spreadsheet/CellView.class

Exception for: impl/org/controlsfx/spreadsheet/GridRow.class
```

and many more errors are included in analysis report, can someone help me.
ps: I'm new in javafx

Comment: update all to a current java/fx version

Comment: Apart from any other issues you may have, NetBeans 8.2 does not support Java 10. Either downgrade to Java 8, or (preferably, if possible) upgrade to newer releases of both NetBeans and Java. See [the end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67238604/2985643) for details on which NetBeans/Java combinations are valid.

Comment: To use netbeans, go to openjfx.io and follow the getting started with net beans guide.  Consider using idea community edition instead with the [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) for a quick and simple setup.  When you go through the wizard and select ControlsFX it will set up a new JavaFX project with a compatible and recent Java, JavaFX and ControlsFX version that will work out of the box without spending a lot of effort installing libraries and configuring the IDE.